# whats the difference between @spawn fetch and @sync @sync in julia

Tags: multithreading, julia

to do multiple work asyncronously (sorting vectors, and function calculation mainly (where the calculations is compute or memory bound,at the moment, i can write those operations in the following ways:

1. using `Threads.@spawn`

```
_f1 = Threads.@spawn f1(x)
_f2 = Threads.@spawn f2(x)
_f3 = Threads.@spawn f3(x)
y1 = fetch(_f1)
y2 = fetch(_f2)
y3 = fetch(_f3)
```

There is also this pattern (seems cleaner):

```
@sync begin
  @async y1 = f1(x)
  @async y2 = f2(x)
  @async y3 = f3(x)
end
```

for this particular use case, which one is preferred?

Comment: You can use `@sync` with `Threads.@spawn` too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Julia has the following support for parallelization (also see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/parallel-computing/)

1. generating SIMD assembly code using `@simd` and `@inbounds` macros (read https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/simd-types/ for more details)
2. Green threading (co-routines) -  these are not actual threads but allow one task to wait for another, typically where the other tasks do not consume CPU on the current thread. Good examples include waiting for intensive I/O operations or orchestration of distributed processes. Green threads are very light and there can be thousands of them but they all are executed within a single (calling) system thread.
3. Threads via the `Threads` module. This allows to spawn actual system threads. The advantage (compared to the next scenario in this list) is that all threads share the same process memory.
4. Multiprocessing/distributed computing via `Distributed` module. The nice thing here is that you can use the same API moving from a single machine to a cluster. In any HPC computing scenario this is the first choice to consider
5. GPU computing

In your post you are considering green threads vs real threads. The rule is simple:

- if your functions `f1`, `f2`, `f3` do mostly I/O and are not CPU intensive (e.g. download files from internet) or wait for other processes to complete - use green threading (`@sync`/`@async`)
- otherwise use `Threads` (or `Distributed` computing). This is particularly important in case of CPU-intensive jobs where green threads will not give you any performance boost as they utilize a single system thread.

Comment: One should write a book on "Parallel coding with Julia".. I would buy it ;-)

Comment: There are several my posts here on parallelizing computations - if you find them all that is more or less everything one needs to know ;-)

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel does Threads module really spawns os threads? As far as I understand “@spawn” is almost the same as “@async” except that it can be scheduled on any available thread and you have to manually await for it

Comment: This is true that the threads are actually "spawned" (=allocated) when Julia is run with the `-t` parameter or  `JULIA_NUM_THREADS` system env var is set. However, `@async` uses green threads which are totally different from os-level threads provided by `Threads`. All green threads will run within a single system thread and hence they only make sense for I/O blocking operations. On the other hand `Threads` can be used for things like parallelizing computations (and `@async` would not provide any advantage in such scenario)